# How to open a hyperlink in an aggrid table without opening a new window?

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

In my streamlit app I have a function to print my dataframe as an aggrid table with a hyperlink in the table.

```
data = {'link': ['https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com', 'https://example3.com'],
    'linkid': ['1', '2', '3']}
df_show = pd.DataFrame(data)

from st_aggrid import AgGrid,JsCode
from st_aggrid.grid_options_builder import GridOptionsBuilder

def show_aggrid_table(df_show): 
    gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df_show)
    gb.configure_pagination(enabled=True, paginationAutoPageSize=False,paginationPageSize=20)
    gb.configure_side_bar()
    gb.configure_default_column(groupable=True, value=True, enableRowGroup=True, aggFunc="sum", editable=True)
    gb.configure_column("link",
                                headerName="link",
                                cellRenderer=JsCode('''function(params) {console.log(params.data);return `<a href="https://example${params.data.linkid}.com" target="_blank">${params.data.linkid}</a>`}'''),
                                width=100)
    gridOptions = gb.build()
    AgGrid(df_show,gridOptions=gridOptions,allow_unsafe_jscode=True,enable_enterprise_modules=True,update_mode="value_changed")
```

This is showing a correct aggrid table. But when I click on the hyperlink a new window opens. I would like to avoid this, any idea on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

In the `JsCode` argument, Change the anchor `a` target from `_blank` to `_self`.

Deference between `_blank` and `_self` target:

Whenever a link target is `_blank`, the linked document will always open in a new browser window or tab when clicked, but if the target is `_self` the linked document will open in the same browser window or tab.